# Empty Listbox is showing in the Listview

Tags: android, listview

i have created a list view in my android project and its showing an empty list at the beginning of the ListView. All the data is showing accurately from the database. but it creates a null list at the top of the List view. for example if we are taking one record from the database, two records are showing. first record is null as shown in the picture here

[image]

I dont know the fault is in the custom adapter or the listview. several days i have searched for an solution and could not find. Please assist me to complete the project. thanks.
below i will past my custom adapter code and the ListView

*Custom Adapter*

```
else {      
LISTVIEW = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

customAdapter = new CustomAdapter();
LISTVIEW.setAdapter(customAdapter);
LISTVIEW.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
LISTVIEW.setStackFromBottom(true);

}


static class ViewHolder {
    TextView ord_num;
    TextView cus_name;
    TextView cus_tel;
    TextView ord_status;
}

class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ID_ArrayList.size() + 1;
    }


    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return -1;
    }


  @Override
  public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {


        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (view == null) {

            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listtemplate, viewGroup,false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.ord_num = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblID);
            holder.cus_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cus_name);
            holder.cus_tel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cus_tel);
            holder.ord_status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ord_status);
            view.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        }


        try {

            holder.ord_num.setText("Order ID :" + ID_ArrayList.get(i));
            holder.cus_name.setText("Name : " + NAME_ArrayList.get(i));
            holder.cus_tel.setText("Telephone No : " + PHONE_NUMBER_ArrayList.get(i));
            holder.ord_status.setText("Status : " + STATUS_ArrayList.get(i));

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }

        final int a=i;

        view.findViewById(R.id.item_info).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, View_Items.class);

                String x = getItem(a).toString();
                String y = ID_ArrayList.get(Integer.parseInt(x)-1).toString();


                AlertDialog.Builder alt = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                        .setTitle("HI")
                        .setMessage(y);

                alt.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {


                    }
                });
                alt.show();

            }
        });

        return (view != null) ? view : null;
```

*Here is My ListView*

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context="com.a_hamoud.listview_sqlserver.MainActivity"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<ListView

    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="8"

    >

</ListView>
```

Please help me to find where the error is.
Thanks.

Comment: You question is not clear. Why you are trying to empty adapter? From where this ( ID_ArrayList ) filled? If possible could you please share more details of code?

Comment: Sir, ID_Arraylist is filled from the database and the values are stored at getter class. the problem is if there is one record in the database its showing two records in the listview while the first one is empty. which codes you want Sir?

Comment: Just return view without condition

Comment: Sir i used return view without condition. but it same thing. i cannot figure out where the error is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change:

```
        holder.ord_num = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblID);
        holder.cus_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cus_name);
        holder.cus_tel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cus_tel);
        holder.ord_status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ord_status);
```

to:

```
        holder.ord_num = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblID);
        holder.cus_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cus_name);
        holder.cus_tel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cus_tel);
        holder.ord_status = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ord_status);
```

Also remove the +1 in getCount(). Hope that helps!

Comment: Sir, i have waited several days by hoping an answer for this. thanks to you now its working. please what can i do for you?

Answer (score 0):

before set text you must check one codition which is null in your list at first index.

```
if (ID_ArrayList.get(i) != null){
holder.ord_num.setText("Order ID :" + ID_ArrayList.get(i));
        holder.cus_name.setText("Name : " + NAME_ArrayList.get(i));
        holder.cus_tel.setText("Telephone No : " + PHONE_NUMBER_ArrayList.get(i));
        holder.ord_status.setText("Status : " + STATUS_ArrayList.get(i));
```

}

```
 i dont know which field is null show you can check.
```

Comment: Sir, all fields are showing correctly. the problem is it is showing an empty list at the begining. for example if we are taking one record from the database, two records are showing. first record is null as shown in the picture above

Comment: sir first you tell me in every record it is happen like if 100 record then show 200 items right ?
or only first item show null and remaining item is proper.
i told you check null value and then set your values as i given above code.

Comment: Yes Sir, only first item show null and remaining item is proper. i used your code with ID_Arraylist but it is same thing.

Comment: please see your adapter ID_ArrayList.size() + 1; remove +1

Comment: i have removed that sir, when removes that, think if we retreive 2 records from the database it shows only one record. but the empty list is showing at the top of the list view.

Comment: when you retrive data from database then check if data is null then not add in list now you will get a list in which orignal data.
this list set in adapter hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

The adapter thinks it has more items than it really has. Remove the +1 in `getCount()`:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return ID_ArrayList.size();
}
```

Comment: Sir, i have used +1 because if we remove that the the last record retrieve from the database is not showing and still the empty list is showing at the top of the list view

Answer (score 0):

Just update your update your getCount method with this one

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return ID_ArrayList.size();
}
```